# Showing all files after selecting/choosing them before final save in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, multifile-uploader

I am developing a project using asp.net 4.7 with visual Studio 2015. I want to upload multiple files with other inputs in the aspx file when I click on the submit button. The requirement is that when I select a file it will be shown in a grid or table or other container. If I select multiple files(one file at a time) all files will be shown in a table/grid. A popup window can also be considered. After selecting a file from popup window I can click on the upload button(in popup window) and the file will be shown in the grid/table in parent window and so on. After clicking on the submit button(in parent form) all data with the file info will be saved. Is it possible by using Ajax or jquery?

Any clue.

Thanks

Partha

Comment: See this pertaining to the AJAX file upload process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: I am working with asp.net not with php.

Comment: Save the files in a temp folder and show them to the user.

Comment: @Partha the main takeaway of the link I shared was the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the very well know plugin "jQuery-File-Upload" http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ (see github https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

On the wiki you see several ASP.net versions https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

For example ASP.Net version : https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3